# Select users from list and add to post request

Tags: django, database, django-templates

I have a list of users that all have a checkbox next to them. All the users that are selected should be added to the array and then sent to the database via the Django post request.

Here is a picture of that:

[image: a busy cat]

The Button at the bottom is the submit button.

models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="", blank=True)

class Studyplan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    parent_assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="studyplan", null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(default=date.today, null=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name="studyplan_students", null=True)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name="studyplan_teachers", null=True)
    canview = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name="studyplan_canview", null=True)
    notes = models.ManyToManyField(Note, blank=True, related_name="studyplan", null=True)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, blank=True, related_name="studyplan", null=True)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True, related_name="studyplan", null=True)
```

Views:

```
@login_required
def skapa_studieplan(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        name = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Name')
        description = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Description') 
        parent_assignment = Assignment.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('Studyplan-PAID'))
        users = UserProfile.objects.all()
        instance = Studyplan.objects.create(request.POST.get('Studyplan-Canview'))
        for user in users:
            instance.canview.add(user)

        studyplan = Studyplan(name=name, description=description, parent_assignment=parent_assignment, canview=instance)
        studyplan.save()

        return redirect('allaStudieplaner')
```

My problem is that I can't figure out to get the values from a ManyToManyField into a POST request.

I get an error similar to this: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use emails_for_help.set() instead

The selection modal:

```
{% for elev in elever %}
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">

                            <span class="d-flex align-items-center">


                                <div style="margin-right: 10px">
                                    <div class="circle" style="background-color: {{ elev.color }}">
                                        <span class="initials" , style="color: #ffffff"> {{ elev.user|capfirst|first }}
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                </div>

                              <div style="width: 300px">

                                <span class="h6 mb-0" data-filter-by="text">{{elev.user|capfirst}}</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="checkboxx"> <input type="checkbox" name="Studyplan-Canview" value= "{{ student.name }}">
                                <style>
                                .checkerName {
                                  margin-left: 10px
                                }

                                .checkboxx {
                                  align-content: flex-end;
                                  margin-left: 300px
                                }
                                </style> </div>

                            </span>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

The Whole HTML:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you remove that picture of your HTML and just paste the selection widget where the users are selected? All the rest is irrelevant. And also can you tell use which field you're asking about? There are many ManyToMany fields in your model, we have no idea which one you're trying to assign the users selected in the HTML form.

Comment: The canview field in the http.post, I want an array off all the users I select inputed into that. And I will paste the selection widget!

Comment: So if you look at your browser dev tools, network tab, what does your POST request look like? Look at the values submitted. Also look at `request.POST` in your debugger.

Comment: And as the error says, you cannot assign values directly to a M2M field, you have to use `set()` or `add()`. Please read and practice [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) to understand how to use M2M relationships.

Comment: i have tried both for hours, could you try to give an example?

Comment: Would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `request.POST` contains a list of usernames for the key `canview`, you'll get a list of the user name like this: `usernames = request.POST.getlist('canview')`.

Now, with the list of usernames, you need to fetch the corresponding users and assign these to your M2M field using `set()`:

```
usernames = request.POST.getlist('canview')
users = User.objects.filter(username__in=usernames)
studyplan = Studyplan(name=name, description=description, parent_assignment=parent_assignment)
studyplan.save()  # you need a saved item to be able to create the M2M relationship
studyplan.canview.set(users)
```