# Make a Django post request to ManyToManyField

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

This is my List in the HTML document
[image]
I have a Django post view, when I hit send I want the selected users to be posted to the **students** field.

As you can see I have tried to do the instance and user thing from [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315357/django-direct-assignment-to-the-forward-side-of-a-many-to-many-set-is-prohibit) but I can't figure it out!

HTML:

```
                        {% for elev in elever %}
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">

                            <span class="d-flex align-items-center">


                                <div style="margin-right: 10px">
                                    <div class="circle" style="background-color: {{ elev.color }}">
                                        <span class="initials" , style="color: #ffffff"> {{ elev.user|capfirst|first }}
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                </div>

                              <div style="width: 300px">

                                <span class="h6 mb-0" data-filter-by="text">{{elev.user|capfirst}}</span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="checkboxx"> <input type="checkbox" name="Studyplan-Canview" value= "{{ student.name }}">
                                <style>
                                .checkerName {
                                  margin-left: 10px
                                }

                                .checkboxx {
                                  align-content: flex-end;
                                  margin-left: 300px
                                }
                                </style> </div>

                            </span>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

The View:

```
#post request checker
@login_required
def skapa_studieplan(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':

    name = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Name')
    description = request.POST.get('Studyplan-Description') 
    parent_assignment = Assignment.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('Studyplan-PAID'))
    users = UserProfile.objects.all()
    instance = Studyplan.objects.create(request.POST.get('Studyplan-Canview'))
    for user in users:
        instance.canview.add(user)

    studyplan = Studyplan(name=name, description=description, parent_assignment=parent_assignment, canview=instance)
    studyplan.save()

    return redirect('allaStudieplaner')
```

Comment: Do not post multiple times the same question, edit your original question to improve it and get feedback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select users from list and add to post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855194/select-users-from-list-and-add-to-post-request)